# What is m/n as n tends to infinity?

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, twin-primes

Here m is in twin prime pair:(6m-1, 6m+1) and n is nth twin prime-pair.
I am just interested to know lower bound of difference of consecutive first twin primes as n tends to infinity.
For example in (5, 7) and (11, 13): Consecutive first twin primes means 5 and 11.
I know that sum of reciprocal of twin primes converges due to Brun' s Constant. So, the sum of reciprocals of first twin primes converges.
I can use Raabe's test which is sufficient to test for convergence. On applying it I can get the lower bound I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is conjectured that there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $n$, $n+2$, $n+6$, and $n+8$ are simultaneously prime (since $\{0,2,6,8\}$ is an "admissible tuple" for the Hardy–Littlewood conjectures). Therefore the best possible lower bound for the difference between consecutive twin primes is $6$. (I'm answering the question in the body of the post—the title does not match it.)

Comment: Why it can't be 4?

Comment: It can't be 4 because if (p, p+2) and (p+4, p+6) are twin pairs then 3 divides p+4 which is not possible so (p+4, p+6) cannot be twin pair. Sorry for asking in comment. But, your answer 6 relies on truthfulness of the conjecture. Can we not prove that m/n tends to 6 as n tends to infinity?

Comment: The symbols $m/n$ don't mean the same thing as the words in the description in the OP, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Raabe's Test for convergence on first of twin pairs: limit n tends to infinity n(p(n+1) -p(n)) /p(n) > 1 implies p(n+1) - p(n) > p(n)/n =(6m-1) /n =6(m/n) - (1/n) = 6*m/n. This is lower bound. What is m/n as n tends to infinity?